# List inside a View

Tags: list, swiftui, view

I've recently started working with SwiftUI. Let me explain my idea: I have a view that allows me to add items to a list. This list should be displayed inside a view. The problem is that I can display it inside, but I can't scroll it or perform a swipe to trigger the .onDelete action. How can I achieve this?

Here is the View with the list:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListInsideScontrino: View {
    
    @State private var isAddFoodViewPresented = false
    @EnvironmentObject var foodData: FoodData
    
    var foodItems: [MyFoodItem] {
        foodData.foodItems
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if foodItems.isEmpty {
            VStack {
                Text("Il riepilogo del tuo ordine apparirà qui una volta aggiunte le varie pietanze.")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()
                
                Text("Clicca il bottone in basso a destra ed inizia ad aggiungere il cibo!")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            .padding()
            
        } else {
            List {
                ForEach(foodData.foodItems) { foodItem in
                    FoodItemRow(foodItem: foodItem)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteFoodItem)
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.100))
        }
        Color.gray.opacity(0.100)
    }
    
    private func deleteFoodItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        foodData.foodItems.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListInsideScontrino()
}
```

This is the view where I want to show my List:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScontrinoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ListInsideScontrino()
        }
        .padding()
        .mask(
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                
                for i in 0..<Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 20) {
                    let x = CGFloat(i) * 20
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + 10, y: 30))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + 20, y: 20))
                }
                
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
                
            }
                .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
        )
        .shadow(radius: 5)
        //.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

I apologize for the errors, I am Italian, and I might have written something incorrectly.

Thank you all for the responses!

I tried to swap views between ScrollView, ZStack ecc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without `.mask` - just putting the scontrino path and the list in a `ZStack`. You just have to make the list background invisible with `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)`

Saluti a Italia

[image]

```
struct ListInsideScontrino: View {
    
    @State private var isAddFoodViewPresented = false
    
    // Test data
    @State private var foodItems: [String] = [
        "Insalata Mista", "Pasta Norcia", "Cotoletta Milanese", "Panna Cotta", "Café", "Gelato", "Digestivo"
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(foodItems, id: \.self) { foodItem in
                Text(foodItem)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear) // remove list row background
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteFoodItem)
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden) // hide overall list background
        //.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.100)) // not needed
    }
    
    private func deleteFoodItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        foodItems.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // first the scontrino
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                
                for i in 0..<Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 20) {
                    let x = CGFloat(i) * 20
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + 10, y: 30))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + 20, y: 20))
                }
                
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
                
            }
            .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
            .shadow(radius: 5)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .ignoresSafeArea()

            // then the list
            ListInsideScontrino()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! This is the solution I was looking for. I've been stucked for days but you solved it. Thanks a lot, you made my day.

Tanti saluti dall'Italia!

Comment: grazie. would be nice if you accept my answer :)